# Темная тема Windows Forms. Вопрос от начинающего программиста

Tags: c#, winforms

Сразу перейду к делу. Задача: я хочу добавить в свое приложение темную тему. Проблема: как узнать какая тема установлена в системе(Windows 10)? Как узнать что тема системы была изменена?

PS: насколько я понял, смена цвета всех элементов происходит "вручную", то есть мне нужно самому прописать что и как должно изменится при смене темы. Если нет, то, пожалуйста, исправьте меня. Также буду благодарен за любую информацию по данной теме.

Comment: Текущая тема прописана в реестре, если точнее, то `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize`. Приложения: `AppsUseLightTheme`, сама система: `SystemUsesLightTheme`. Автоматизация - тут надо смотреть на события системы, как я написал под ответом, есть библиотека для WPF, зовется WPF UI, там есть класс [Watcher](https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui/blob/main/src/Wpf.Ui/Appearance/Watcher.cs), который в случаи события [WM_WININICHANGE](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-wininichange) меняет тему.  Можете попробовать и другие события.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ _Сообщение WM_WININICHANGE предоставляется только для совместимости с более ранними версиями системы. Приложения должны использовать сообщение WM_SETTINGCHANGE ._ Это соообщение возникает не при изменении темы, а при изменении настроек ОС. Так что нет гарантии, что если оно прилетело, то тема обязательно изменилась.

Comment: @aepot Пример выше я брал из библиотеки WPF UI, почему они этот эвент взяли - не знаю, я лишь дал то, что знаю и то, что проверено. `при изменении настроек ОС` - что мешает сверить новое и старое значение реестра? Если одинаковы - тема не изменилась, если отличаются - изменилась. Тут главное факт, что подобное позволяет автоматизировать смену темы. Еще есть [WM_THEMECHANGED](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-themechanged), но я не совсем уверен, что это именно темная/светлая тема OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Forms не поддерживает смену тем ОС, как и любое Win32 приложение, например WPF.

Смену тем поддерживают только WinRT приложения, например UWP, либо совместимые с WinRT приложения типа Windows App SDK / WinUI 3, при чем нативно.

То есть, в совместимых приложениях цвет UI меняется автоматически, и ничего для этого дополнительно в коде писать не нужно.

Вы конечно можете сами написать внутри WinForms приложения менялку тем и сами написать перекрашивание интерфейса, но это никак не будет интегрировано с операционной системой. Win32 API не предоставляет никаких сервисов, чтобы взаимодействовать с системными темами.

**UPD:** Изменения темы для приложений можно [узнать в реестре](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62282762/12888024) `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize`, ключ `AppsUseLightTheme`, а изменение можно отслеживать перехватывая Windows сообщение [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange). Для этого надо вклиниться в работу `WndProc`, с этим вам может помочь реализация интерфейса `IMessageFilter`.

Comment: `Win32 API не предоставляет никаких сервисов` - о каких сервисах речь? Получить текущую тему винды без проблем можно, как и реализовать "мониторинг" смены темы в OS. Для WPF например есть WPF UI, который позволяет сделать проект в современном, Win11 виде, он без труда определяет текущую тему системы, а также [автоматически](https://wpfui.lepo.co/documentation/themes) меняет ее при переключении темы (даже вроде акцента) самой винды, и работает это вроде начиная с Win7. Так что, как по мне, это очень странный ответ, ибо он говорит "нет, вы это не сделаете, используйте WinUI".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я разве что-то писал про ненативные решения? Если вкрутить кучу сторонних библиотек и хорошенько попотеть, можно даже в консоли смену тем устроить, нет ничего невозможного в мире программирования. Я написал что в винформах поддержки нет, в Win API тоже, я ошибся? То что нативно поддержку смены тем предоставляет только WinRT, я наврал? Странный комментарий, перечитайте вопрос, человек спрашивал, надо вручную пилить цвета контролам или есть поддержка. Быть может она где-то в глубине нугет-пакетов и есть, быть может даже платных, мне об этом не известно. Если вам известно, поделитесь.

Comment: Вопрос звучит "как узнать какая тема установлена? Как узнать что тема системы была изменена?". Ответ "Windows Forms не поддерживает смену тем ОС, как и любое Win32 приложение". Далее, в вопросе "буду благодарен за любую информацию по данной теме" - ответ "Смену тем поддерживают только WinRT приложения. ... в совместимых приложениях цвет UI меняется автоматически". Другими словами "Нет, вы это сделать не можете, этой поддержки нет, используйте WinRT". Я лично так понимаю ваш ответ. Далее "никак не будет интегрировано" - подпись на `WM_WININICHANGE` и чтение реестра - это разве не интеграция?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Возможно, но это костыли. И да, WPF прекрасен и легендарен, но это уже устаревшая технология, как WinForms, Windows 7 или 8.1. "Лошадь умерла - слезай". Хотя в России наверное еще лет 15 будут семеру крутить в офисах, как это было с XP. Страна динозавров, в этом плане вы конечно же правы. WinUI 3 - пока не панацея, ее еще не скоро до ума доведут, делаю ставку годика на 2. Но там не только смена тем есть, а наверное еще кое что из того чего нет в Win32, верно? И да, половину фичей можно накостылить самому, но зачем, когда можно писать сразу код там, где всё уже есть?

Comment: Костыль или нет - автор вопроса ведь не искал "решения из коробки", я лично такого не вижу в вопросе. Я вижу "как" эту задачу решить, а сейчас у меня такое впечатление, что он услышал "такое невозможно" и забил на эту идею, что в корне неверно. Или я не прав? `Лошадь умерла - слезай` - не предлагайте людям то, что им может не подойти. Вот я допустим поддерживаю проект для игры, игра поддерживает Win7+, часть людей до сих пор сидит на Win7. Что, предложите мне использовать WinUI и бросить эту часть аудитории? У всех свои требования, а гнать всех на "современное", не есть хорошо. + WinUI сыра.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ дополнил ответ, я вам ничего не предлагаю и автору тоже, не читайте между строк. Люди просто так WinForms не выбирают, обычно это либо новички-ученики, либо столкнувшиеся с динозаврами разрабы. WinUI сыра, но уже позволяет пилить вменяемый софт, разница с WPF минимальна по трудозатратам, для учебы вполне сойдет.

Comment: `WPF прекрасен и легендарен, но это уже устаревшая технология` а какая замена? я просто для себя интересуюсь, у меня есть пет проект, которому уже 7 лет, и я его еще столько же развивать планирую - он как раз на WPF и только под винду. Что то есть на рынке, что через 7 лет точно будет живо? (про WPF у меня сомнений нет, он живее всех живых будет)